# How to update UIView background smoothly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, uiview

in my app I want to change the background of an uiview based on camera, All works properly but the problem is the background is changed too sharply (I think because of the focus).

So there's a way to change the background color of a UIView smoothly?

I actually use this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        [myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1]];
});
```

The UIVIew animation solution doesn't work beacause the changes are too fast.

Comment: What is your code for the UIView animation? The length is customisable in these so you should be able to slow it down.

Comment: I use the UIView animateWithDuration: animations: method but even if I put a duration od 0.003 seconds, changes are not smooth

Answer (score 0):

Just before setting the background colour do something like;

```
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:0.2f];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
[transitionAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
[myview layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:@"fadeAnimation"];
```

Hopefully this will give you a gentle fade in colour change.

Comment: That doesn't work, maybe in 0.2 seconds the background is changed 8 o 9 times because I get the data from the camera and it updates the view on real time

Comment: Ok, I think I may have misunderstood your original question. Does reducing the SetDuration to a much faster value help?

Comment: No, I've tried. I think that the only solution if I want to do all on real time is to leave the background changes sharply. thanks anyway